# Uncaught ReferenceError: RailsAdmin is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My RailsAdmin is working good but such things like progress bars, multi checkboxes and dropdown lists are not working. Moreover, this problem is seen only in production mode. At my localhost it's fine. At production I have these errors in my browser's console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: RailsAdmin is not defined

How can I make javascript to execute in RailsAdmin panel  in production mode?

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe the reason was that I kicked out jquery-ujs and added rails-ujs? Did you do anything similar?

Comment: @morgler the problem was in Gemfile.lock. I reverted to previous version and it worked. Still don't know what was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary solution** that worked for me was copying `<path to gems>rails_admin/app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/rails_admin.js` file to `<yourapp>/app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/rails_admin.js`

and changing `//=  require 'jquery'` to `//=  require 'jquery2'`
which loads jQuery 2 instead of jQuery 3.

Still not sure where exactly is the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Me also I haven't a definitive solution, but only a stupid trick:

using **target: '_self'** as below

```
link_to "admin page", rails_admin_path, target: '_self'
```

and for me the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I would wager that you haven't uploaded the javascript files.

You can verify this by looking in your browsers console, in particular, the network panel; so in Chrome, this:

[image]

The other issue could be you're referencing your files with a relative path and your local development environment may have a virtual directory, where your production one doesn't. I.E local could be `localhost/mysite` and production simple `mysite.com` - again this would result in a 404 trying to load the files.

The long-and-short of this is the error is basically saying "there is no RailsAdmin variable or object, are you sure you loaded one"